# TFS 2018 - How to view complete history for each test case

Tags: tfs

We are running TFS version 2018 RTW (16.122.27102.1). I am trying to view the complete run history for my each of my test cases. I am only seeing the last couple of test runs when I go to the Build -> Tests -> Click on a test -> Right panel shows a graph with the link "View History" below it. The graph is only showing the last couple of test runs:
 [image]

The Build definition I am working with has a retention policy of 15 days and a minimum to keep of 3. TFS seems to be only showing history for builds it has not yet deleted. However, the box "Automated test results" is not checked - I am under the impression that not checking this box should allow me to see the completed history of my test runs.

How can I view the completed history of my test runs without having to retain all my builds?

**Additional Details**

My build specific retention policy is listed first. This means it will override the global policy if I understand correctly.
[image]

I can see all the test runs for my deleted builds. However the test history for each individual test only shows 3 bars. I was expecting to see 8 bars (the current 3 plus the 5 test runs from the deleted builds).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are not only the build retention policy in your build definition, but also a **[Global build retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention?view=vsts#global-build-retention-policy)**

Global build retention policy settings can be managed from the Build and Release settings of your account or team project collection:

TFS 2018: `https://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_buildQueue`

[image]

You could **not be able** to change the **delete test results** value in the policy there. So if your builds fit the global policy, the test result will still be deleted.

---

Besides, you could use the **REST API** to get the test case and Test Run list.

However, it's not so easy to get the test run history for a specific test case, unless you run only the specific test case each time. In fact, usually we will run multiple test cases in a test run.

[REST API to get the test case](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/cases#get-a-test-case),

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/_apis/test/plans/105/suites/106/testcases/107?api-version=1.0
```

[REST API to get the test run list](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/runs#get-a-list-of-test-runs) :

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/_apis/test/Runs/
```

> Actually the best way to retrieve test cases run status history is
>   using MTM (Microsoft Test Manager):
>
> Connect TFS server -->> Select the Team Project -->> Select  **Test**
>   tab >> Select the test plan -->> Select the specific test case -->>
>   **View Results** -->> At the end of the opened page you will see the result history (All test runs for the specific test case).

[image]

Comment: If I understand the retention policy correctly my build specific policy should override the global policy. Also, I can see all the test runs, even for my deleted builds but the test history graph only shows 3 bars... please see my additional details added.

Answer (score 1):

We also found that the ability to view easily view a test cases' result history was lost when we moved from MTM.

There is a feature request uservoice here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2037641-provide-more-visibility-for-a-test-case-s-result-s

However, if you have got MTM handy, you can use the the following workaround

1) In TFS, click on "Test" from the top menu and select the test suite where your test case is. Select the test case that you are interested in. Then Click pass or fail button. This will generate a manual test run for the given test.

[image]

2) Go to MTM -> Test  --> Analyze Test Run. Select option "Manual Runs" in the View option.
[image]

3) Open the test run. Right click on test and click "View Results"
[image]

4) The list of results will show you the manual run as well as automated runs, which is what you are looking for.
[image]

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have MTM. What's confusing me is that I can see the test runs for the deleted builds but the test history graph only shows 3 bars... please see the additional details added to my question.